# Drop column if all values equal a string value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe like this, `df`:

```
Date      Time Black Carbon Carbon monoxide  PM10                    Particulate matter
0  19/10/2015  01:00:00      No data         No data                 No data   
1  19/10/2015  02:00:00      No data         No data                 No data   
2  19/10/2015  03:00:00      10              No data                 No data   
3  19/10/2015  04:00:00      No data         11 .                    No data   
4  19/10/2015  05:00:00      No data         No data                 No data
```

I can remove all na columns via:

```
tmp_df= df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

However, I wish to delete a column, on the condition that every row contains a string, `No data`

In this case, we would remove the `Particulate matter` column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want columns such that not all columns equal `No data`.

```
df.loc[:, ~(df.astype(str) == 'No data').all()]
```

Output

```
                  Date Time Black Carbon Carbon monoxide     PM10
0 19/10/2015  01:00:00                           No data  No data
1 19/10/2015  02:00:00                           No data  No data
2 19/10/2015  03:00:00                                10  No data
3 19/10/2015  04:00:00                           No data     11 .
4 19/10/2015  05:00:00                           No data  No data
```

Comment: I keep getting: `TypeError: Could not compare ['No data'] with block values`

Comment: @LearningSlowly: `df.loc[:, ~(df.values == 'No data').all(axis=0)]` works for me. Alternatively, you can also check my solution below although it is more complex.

Comment: @TedPetrou: I receive `TypeError: Could not compare ['No data'] with block values`; `df.values == 'No data'`, works though but I still need the `axis=0` part (see comment above and my answer below). Not fully sure what the cause is though. Do you use Python3 or a newer pandas version?

Comment: @Cleb My bad. You need to convert all columns to strings first. Convert the whole frame with `astype(str)`. It worked for me because all the columns were string from my import reading from the clipboard.

Comment: @TedPetrou: That indeed works now (upvoted). Not sure what is more efficient; converting to strings or just using `.values`. But at least there are now alternatives OP can choose from :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1 and x[0]=='No data', axis=0)]
```

That i) checks whether there is only one element in the column using `nunique` and ii) whether the first element of the column is equal to your string.

Demonstration:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3), columns=list('abc'))
df1['d'] = 'No data'
df1['e'] = ['No data', 0, 'No data']

          a         b         c        d        e
0 -0.441122  3.499830 -0.161578  No data  No data
1  1.683904  0.217083 -1.167220  No data        0
2 -1.143193 -0.386444 -0.403479  No data  No data
```

Then

```
df1.loc[:, ~df1.apply(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1 and x[0]=='No data', axis=0)]
```

returns

```
          a         b         c        e
0 -0.441122  3.499830 -0.161578  No data
1  1.683904  0.217083 -1.167220        0
2 -1.143193 -0.386444 -0.403479  No data
```

EDIT:

As an alternative to @Ted Petrou's answer:

```
df1.loc[:, ~(df1.values == 'No data').all(axis=0)]
```

I don't know, however, whether it is more efficient to convert all values to strings as in his answer or to just use `.values`.